# How to get the Ubuntu Studio 20.04 LTS version when we have Ubuntu Studio 18.04

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-studio

I have Ubuntu Studio 18.04.4 in one desktop PC and I want to upgrade it to 20.04 LTS, but... There is not any warning about that from the official repository, yet.

So... I wonder if there is some way to get the last version in a "manual" way (Maybe a command line?)

Any idea will be welcome!

Comment: The upgrade will be offered when 20.04.1 is released.

Comment: @Ollie, FYI: the listed date is an ETA for ISO release (for new installs; always a Thursday), the upgrade *taps* don't get turned on till the following Mon-Wed of the following week usually, and that can gets delayed (if issues occur on new installs), so it won't be on July 23 even if there are no delays...

Comment: Ahh, okay.  Thank you guiverc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure your system is up to date

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Next, *take a backup*. This is important as if anything goes wrong you will still have your data. You can use Deja Dup among other tools.

To upgrade to 20.04 run the following command and answer the questions:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

**Note**: The `-d` flag denotes that you are upgrading to a development version. When the first point release happens, then you will get the official repository asking you to upgrade. It is recommended that you wait for 20.04.1 to be released before upgrading as any bug reports will be ironed out after that. 20.04.1 is being released on July 23, 2020.

*After* July 23, 2020 you can upgrade to the Focal by running the following command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Ubuntu Studio 20.04 Focal Fossa release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuStudio) include details on how to upgrade, as does this [entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades/UbuntuStudio) in the Ubuntu Community Help Wiki.

According to the release notes, you can upgrade if you are running Ubuntu Studio 18.04 or 19.10.

#### Preparations

Before you start, you should backup your data and make sure your current packages are up to date.

Most Ubuntu Studio 18.04 installs would have the Backports PPA enabled. If this is the case, you should remove it.

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntustudio-ppa/backports
```

Whether using a command line or GUI method, you'll likely be asked a few questions about keeping or replacing configuration files for packages

#### Command Line Upgrades

From a command prompt, type: `sudo do-release-upgrade -d -m desktop`

The `-d` flag is needed until the first point release (eg 20.04.1) is available.